# How to read a file when building a python package

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am building a python package which looks like the following structure for now :

```
my_pkg
   |- setup.py
   |- __init__.py
   |- main_func.py
   |- utils
         |- __init__.py
         |- mod1.py
         |- text.txt
         |- mod2.py
```

in `mod1.py` file, I have a function must use `text.txt`, this is how I work for reading `text.txt` file for now :

```
with open("./text.txt","rb") as f:
    content = f.readline()
```

But after I ran `setup.py` to install and import it, there is always an error :

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   './text.txt'

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Final I make it work

```
import pkg_resources    
stream = pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, 'text.txt')
with stream as s:
    content = Template(s.read().decode())
```